# Kubernetes kubectl get secrets by type?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to run kubectl and get all the secrets of type = X. Is this possible?

I.e if I want to get all secrets where type=tls

something like `kubectl get secrets --type=tls`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it [`jsonpath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/). Something like this:

```
$ kubectl get secret -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {.type}{"\n"}{end}' | grep -i tls
```

For example, to get all the type `Opaque` secrets:

```
$ kubectl get secret -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {.type}{"\n"}{end}' | grep Opaque
dummy-secret Opaque
mysecretdelete Opaque
```

*Update:*

Now you can do this with the `--field-selector` option in `kubectl`:

```
$ kubectl get secrets --field-selector type=kubernetes.io/tls
$ kubectl get secret --field-selector type=kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Answer (score 32):

How about [field-selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/):

```
$ kubectl get secrets --field-selector type=kubernetes.io/tls
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer certainly works, but I was interested in finding a `grep`-less solution. Here's my contribution.

```
$ kubectl get secret -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.type=="Opaque")].metadata.name}'
dummy-secret mysecretdelete
```